# Render different .js file with Rails Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

How do you render a different `.js.erb` file while using Ajax?

For example:

```
<% form_tag user_path, :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
```

This goes through the `UserController#show` and then renders `users/show.js.erb`. How do I make it go through the `UserController#show` and then render `users/hello.js.erb`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In **users_controller.rb**:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'hello.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

or shorter as there is only one respond format:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :hello
end
```