# How to render partial .js.erb file inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i tried to find the example, but it's hard to find any, so
can you give example code how to render other file (in my case is .js.erb file) inside JS?
let say i want to render it inside like this:

```
$("#btn").click(function(e) {
  // render partial .js.erb file in here
}
```

Thanks

Comment: the better way to render js file is https://stackoverflow.com/a/9170967/10739704

Comment: @nileshkumar i don't want inside the controller, it must on JS, is that imposible?

Comment: Just use `<%= render(partial: "partial_name") %>` and make sure that the js partial is following Rails naming conventions.

Comment: How can i write the format tag like that inside jquery? it's still not inside .js.erb file but it's on html
take a look at my example code above, it's on button click action
@spickermann

Comment: You can only include partials in ERB files. That means into HTML that is generated with ERB or into JS that is generated with ERB. When you have JS code that is not processed with ERB, for example, code from an internal source, then you obviously cannot include partials. That means if you want to use partials then the files that should include the partials need to be generated with ERB too.